# Why do semaphores use errno while mutexes return the error directly?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

The docs for `pthread_mutex_trylock` (and friends) say

> If successful, the pthread_mutex_lock() and pthread_mutex_unlock() functions shall
> return zero; otherwise, an error number shall be returned to indicate the error.

Cool. Makes sense, If we're doing `try_lock` we probably want to access the result to check if it locked or not. Nice and fast.

But for some reason `sem_trywait` returns `-1` on error and sets `errno`! Not only this, but instead of doing `EBUSY`, we get `EAGAIN`!

This seems like a weird and arbitrary design difference. What are the reasons for it?

Comment: Arbitrary? Maybe. Weird? I don't think so, both are legit.

Comment: It's weird that `pthread_*` returns the value `errno` should have instead of setting `errno`. I'm guessing this is to support systems where `errno` isn't thread-specific. But again, that's just a guess.

Comment: `EAGAIN` is used for operations that would block all the time (e.g. reading from a non-blocking socket that has no data ready), so that makes sense. But it looks like `EBUSY` would also make sense. So neither choices looks weird to me.

Comment: @ikegami Re: _"guessing this is to support systems where errno isn't thread-specific"_ - that would be my guess too since `pthread_*` is older than C11 and `errno` wasn't specified to be thread-local before C11.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Is <semaphore.h> not also older than C11?

Comment: @doliphin Probably, but when using the `pthread` API, using a global `errno` in one thread while another thread sets it would make `errno` impossible to use. I'm therefore guessing that mixing threads and reading from `errno` (for _any_ reason) was a bit dodgy before C11. If one thread set `errno` for failing to open a file, another thread could check it after doing something completely different and then get a surprising `errno`. I think that would have required mutexes around all calls that could set `errno` in order to assure proper results.

Comment: Well yes but in practice `errno` has been a multithreaded macro for > 30 years.

Comment: @user207421 Ever since posix threads were created in 1995 with IEEE std 1003.1c-1995? Before NPTL (circa 2004), linux used "linuxthreads" and it had posix compatible threads in the 1990s. When threads were added, `errno` needed to become a per-thread variable. But, linux (kernel) had _no_ per-thread variable support, so `errno` became a macro that called `errno_location`. When the _kernel_ support for threads arrived (along with NPTL), it had support for per-thread variables (e.g. `__thread` in the compiler) but `errno` remained a macro.

Comment: Basically because they where introduced by different development teams. :)